# Can someone help me to identify this bike model

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

It's a "Focus" road bike, from 2013 or 2014 (I think).

Can someone tell me the exact model ?

Thanks a lot !

[image]

Comment: Need a lot more info from you.  What's the frame material - Aluminium or carbon?  Whats the groupset - ultegra, 105, or tiagra?  What's written on the chainstay and seat stay?

Comment: The only info I have is "aluminiu frame and carbon fork"

Comment: Fairly generic newer road bike.  Decent quality.  Never heard of the "Focus" brand before.  Unless someone here actually has that model it's unlikely that you can narrow it down much more than what Criggie's answer provides.

Comment: Based on the images on their website the name of the model is either is across the top tube (the white graphics in your image) or possibly along the drive side chainstay.  More pictures might help, clearly showing the drive train an the other graphics on the bike.

Comment: Have you tried contacting focus directly?

Comment: An almost new road bike that you or the previous seller know nothing about? Sounds stolen to me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the current lineup of 2016, I'd guess its a Cayo, because their other models have radially spoked front wheels.  However that could have changed in the last three years.

http://www.focus-bikes.com/us/en/bikes/2016/road/performance-cayo-al.html

Their website was the top match on google for "focus road bike"

Comment: Thanks. I know it looks like a lot to a 2016 Cayo. I'm looking for the exact model. I've spend a lot of time on google image looking for "2013 focus road bike" or "2014 focus road bike", "2015 focus road bike", "2016 focus road bike" to find the same model, without any chance

Comment: @Aurelien so look for a "focus cayo 2013" and see what you get.

Comment: Also, if you click search tools -> color -> red you'll get more red bicycles.